# Magento overriding sql upgrade scripts?

Tags: magento

How can I override upgrade scripts in magento lying in sql folder?

I know how to setup new module with tables and all. I know install scripts will run only once. But I want to know how to override or change something in table with existing value.

I wanted to run a sql query so that I can change Customer attribute in the database. For example I want to change 'frontend_label' in 'eav_attribute' table for 'First Name' to 'Company Name'.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is to bump your extension version number and make a new upgrade script for your task

Comment: but how could i run an upgrade script, I mean i am not overloading controller. sorry i m new to it and I'm bit confused. could please provide some pseudocode

Comment: no need for controller override.
just create update script.
increase module version.
and it will run automatically

Comment: yes it will work  if i do that in core customer module(increase the module version and upgrade the sql script) but is it the right way to do that. I mean they say don't touch core files.. use local

Comment: no it is not the right way you need to make your own extension and customize in a upgrade script there. Idea stays the same

Answer (score 0):

If you are only developing, you don't have to mess with upgrade scripts. Those are a hassle.

Run this MySQL code:

```
DELETE FROM core_resource WHERE code = 'mymodulename_setup';
```

To make things easier, you could create your own method or action to do this too, adding functionality to the following as needed:

```
public function removeMyModuleAction() {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM 'core_resource'
                  WHERE 'code' = 'mymodule_setup';";

    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    try {
        $connection->query($sql);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When you remove this row from the `core_resource table`, Magento will run the initial install script again. No need to fiddle with upgrades. Of course if you are publishing your module, the upgrade script will be necessary.